# Is there a way to show 'Total Records' in a chart(Report) in salesforce?

Tags: reporting, charts, report-chart

I would like to show Total records count in a bar chart in salesforce, but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Guess it is not possible and we have to use Donut type instead. I have seen people adding Metric Component above the chart as a workaround (https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063000000049nTAAQ). There is an idea as well which I believe is related - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BriNAAS

Comment: Thank you but I was wondering how do I add metric component above or below a chart ?

Comment: I haven't used it either but it appears that metric component is available as a Dashboard Component and it is used to show a single value to display. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dashboards_component_types.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks but I still cannot figure it out on how did they even accomplish that.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks though ;)

Comment: @user3920709 If you figured out then good to share your results as an answer to your own question so that others are benefited if they have same issue.